# How to receive non valid Ethernet frames?

Tags: ethernet, crc

I'm sending/receiving Ethernet frames and i provoke some transmission errors by generating interference in the cable. (the frames are sent using a client/server program with sockets)

The PHY detects the errors (crc calculation) and drops the frames with errors (my program don't receive it). I'm trying to find a way to receive this non valid frames.

In an other way, i want to receive the erroneous frames like a receive the valid ones in my program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

tell us more about your configuration, are you using a router between server side and client side?, a router can block packets with invalid crc, tell us more please

Comment: Non, it's a point to point connection between two PCs turning on Ubuntu. I'm using intel 1000 pro Ethernet card.

Comment: Ubuntu can be dropping the frames at low level software, it's too difficult to bypass crc checksum at user level environment, Unluckely, i don't know what you can use to your purpose, try to receive a response for an ethernet expert

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm trying to find. Thank you for your response.